# How to resolve http response before loading data-table in angularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring-mvc

In below code, First I am calling a service to do a http request.
Then using the response I am creating a map which I am using later.
Next in data-table calling a new http request and using above map doing some operation before displaying data.

Problem: I know $http will take some time to get the response. I am trying to use promise but I am failing to do so. Please suggest me How do I use promise so that the first http is resolved and map is created before second http call.

```
//Call to service to do a http call
    MasterServices.getAllCustomers().then(function(result) {
            $scope.resultdata= result.data;
            $scope.resultdata.forEach(element => {
            //creating map holding id, name
            $scope.oumap.set(element.companyId,element.companyName)
            });
        });
    
    //Setting Data-Table
    vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromFnPromise(function() {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        
        //Calling http call to get some configuration data
        MasterServices.getCompConfig().then(function(result) {
            
            angular.forEach(result.data,function(val){
                if($scope.oumap.has(val.compId)){
                    val.companyName=$scope.oumap.get(val.compId);
                }else{
                    val.companyName=" ";
                }
            });
            defer.resolve(result.data); 
        });
        return defer.promise;
    }).withPaginationType('full_numbers').withOption('createdRow', createdRow);
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the ecmascript version you are targeting, this would be much simpler if you wrote in the form of async-await.

```
// You may need to use a try-catch to account for the http request failing
const result = await MasterServices.getAllCustomers();
$scope.resultdata = result.data;
$scope.resultdata.forEach(element => {
    //creating map holding id, name
    $scope.oumap.set(element.companyId,element.companyName)
});

// Http response is complete, continue doing other things.
```

If you cannot use the above for some reason, you need to place your "Setting Data-Table" section of code inside the success callback of the first promise.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No success using async await.  Can't move the data-table inside the function. As there are more code belongs to data-table.

Comment: You may be able to propagate the async-await pattern to your other http calls. It will make it much easier to reason about instead of wrapping everything with then-able callbacks.

Comment: Even using async await the data table is loaded before response is received. My requirement is to display company name instead of ID. As company is in different table so trying to do another api call and manipulate the existing response

Comment: It's a bit overkill, but you could put an ngIf on your table to prevent it from being rendered before the data is present.